# python - get all possible permutations with replacement without recursion

Tags: python, string, permutation

In python, how can I write a function that get some number n and print all possible words(a-z) permutations(with replacement) when `length=n`.

Without using recursion and without using external functions like `itertools.permutations`, `itertools.combinations` etc..

For example:
`n=2` should print

```
aa ba ... za
ab bb ... zb
...
az bz ... zz
```

`n=3`

```
aaa baa ... zaa
aba aca ... aza
aab aac ... aaz
abb abc ... abz
acb acc ... acz
...
azz bzz ... zzz
```

Comment: See the code in the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: I think it is important that you say 'with replacement'... at least that is what you are doing in your examples

Comment: The correct link for combinations_with_replacement is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement

Comment: @mtk99 this examples doenst print the opposite (print "ab" but doesnt print "ba"). I can use "reverse" but I'm pretty sure there is better way

Comment: [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: @vaultah it doesnt print replacements and opposites, as i wrote to mtk99. plus I dont want to get the iterable objects, I know I can fill it by myself in a tuple with a-z but I think maybe there is better way

Comment: @mtk99 it was very useful, thank u !

Comment: Those **are not** "combinations with replacement", since you want to generate for example `'az'` and `'za'`. By definition, combinations include elements only in the same order that they appeared in the input. The question title said "combinations", but the body says "permutations" - these are **not the same thing**. "Permutations with replacement" are equivalent to a Cartesian product of a sequence with itself. I have closed the question as a duplicate, and fixed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are counting. Here is an example. A tried to keep it simple so it is easy to follow:

```
def get_string(idxlist, item_list):
    return ''.join([item_list[i] for i in idxlist])

def increment_vector(idxlist, max_count):
    idxlist[0] += 1
    for i in xrange(len(idxlist)-1):
        if idxlist[i] < max_count:
            break
        idxlist[i]=0
        idxlist[i+1] += 1

def generate(n, item_list):
    max_count = len(item_list)

    idxlist = [0] * n
    while idxlist[-1] < max_count:
        print ( get_string( idxlist, item_list )),
        increment_vector(idxlist, max_count)
        if idxlist[0]==0:
            print 

item_list = map(chr, range(97, 123)) # letters from a-z

generate(3, item_list)
```

The only point where you really work with your items is in get_string.

EDIT: small adjustment so the output is formatted like in your question